# Compare 2 dates with current year

Tags: php

I am comparing 2 dates and check if the current project is expired or not.Working fine with some cases, but what I need is to compare with the current year.

```
$time_before = strtotime('1-Apr-16');// from excel sheet date format
$date_before = date('y-m-d', $time_before);
$time_after = strtotime('31-May-16'); // from excel sheet date format
$date_after = date('y-m-d', $time_after); // 2016-12-31
echo "<br/><br/><br/><br/>";
$datetime1 = new DateTime($date_before);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date_after);
if($datetime1>$datetime2){echo "expired";}else{echo "active";}

Use Case1:
$time_before = '01-04-16';
$time_after = '31-05-16';
Result=active //where as it what I am expecting to return expired since 2016 is passed.

Use Case2:
$time_before = '28-01-17';
$time_after = '28-02-17';
Result=expired //working fine.
```

Comment: When project is expired. Can you give a clean rule?

Comment: You can follow use-cases mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not an alpha and omega. Give a clean business rule.

Answer (score 0):

**The constructor argument has wrong format.** After `new DateTime('31-05-16');` the instance will be represent a date like `2031-05-16`.

When you sure about date format use `createFromFormat` method to create a new instance of DateTime and then compare with other instances.

**Example**

```
 //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$time_before = '01-04-16';
$time_after = '31-05-16';

$datetime1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_before);
$datetime2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_after);
```

**Test**

```
$time_before = '01-04-16';
$time_after = '31-05-16';

$datetime1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_before);
$datetime2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_after);

\assert(
    $datetime1 < $datetime2,
    "Project is expired"
);    

$time_before = '28-01-17';
$time_after = '01-01-17';

$datetime1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_before);
$datetime2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $time_after);

\assert(
    $datetime1 > $datetime2,
    "Project is active"
);
```

Comment: Just edit my question, I am getting date from excel converted format, thats why coverting into proper format. Yours is not working as I am expecting.

Comment: Now you create correct instance of DateTime. You're fixed a bug. I think you're making a logical error.